# Returning most recent row in table from a join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables.  Consider them Table A and Table B.

Table A has a list of *things* in it.

Table B **might** have entries which point back to the *things* in Table A.

That is to say, for every row in Table A, there may be 0 rows or *n* rows in Table B that link back to it (via some ID column also in Table B).

What I want to do is run 1 SELECT statement with some kind of JOIN which returns a list of all the rows from Table A (all columns) and 1 column from Table B where that 1 column from Table B is ordered DESC (the column is a timestamp, and I want the most recent timestamp).

That is to say, I want my SELECT statement to return 1 row for each row in Table A.  One of the columns in the result set will be data from Table B, and it has to grab the data from the most recent entry corresponding to the Table A row.

I'm really at a loss on how to do this.  I've even tried adding "TableB.created_on = max(TableB.created_on)" to the ON clause of the JOIN.

Comment: Please give some `schema` for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sample schema  looks like

```
CREATE TABLE a
    (id INT, description VARCHAR(64)); 
CREATE TABLE b
    (id INT, timestamp timestamp);
```

You can do

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
          FROM b 
         WHERE id = a.id) max_timestamp
FROM a
```

or

```
SELECT a.id, a.description, MAX(b.timestamp)
  FROM a JOIN b 
    ON a.id = b.id
 GROUP BY a.id, a.description
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10978/3)** (for both queries)

Comment: @Andrew Do you need more help with your question?